# label variable for stargazer extraction

Tags: r, label, stargazer, expss

I am using **stargazer** to extract some regression tables in latex.
I would to know if it exists a way to label variables once for all **without** having to re-define it through "*covariate.labels = ...*" every time. 
I tried the library **expss** (and **Hmisc**), such as:

```
library(expss)
library(stargazer)

df <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,100,rep=TRUE)))

df = apply_labels(df,
                  X1 =  "label x1",
                  X2 = " label x2")

ols <- lm(formula = X1 ~ X2,
          data= df)

stargazer(ols, 
          # covariate.labels = NULL, 
          title = "Regression Results",
          label = "tab:test",
          out="test.tex")
```

without success... 
any suggestion?

Comment: Could you provide example of your code? Generally speaking, you can try `use_labels` from expss `package`. In many cases it can utilize labels for functions which doesn't apply it.

Comment: executing the code above I obtain X2 as covariate var name while I would like to have "label x2"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with expss `use_labels`:

```
library(expss)
library(stargazer)

df <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,100,rep=TRUE)))

df = apply_labels(df,
                  X1 =  "label x1",
                  X2 = " label x2")

ols <- use_labels(df, lm(formula = X1 ~ X2))

res <- stargazer(ols, 
          # covariate.labels = NULL, 
          title = "Regression Results",
          label = "tab:test",
          out="test.tex")

# quick and dirty workaround for removing backticks  
remove_backticks = function(text){
    text = gsub("([^A-z]+)`", "\\1", text, perl = TRUE)
    text = gsub("`([^A-z]+)", "\\1", text, perl = TRUE)
    text = gsub("(^`)|(`$)", "", text, perl = TRUE)
    text
}


res = remove_backticks(res)

writeLines(res, "test.tex")
```

Comment: doen't works for me!
it gives me the following message:
"Error: `x` and `labels` must be same type"

Comment: @TeYaP It is conflict with some other package - I suppose with `haven` or `labelled`. Try to restart you R session and `expss` should be loaded after the all other packages.

Comment: Thanks, I had indeed a conflict issue. Your solution is now partially working. The label included in the latex extraction is : ‘ label x2‘ . Does it exists a way to delete the quote marks? And, if I may ask another question: do you know another way, more aesthetic, to produce similar results, maybe using other libraries?

Comment: @TeYaP I've added function for removing backticks. It's rather quick and dirty but should work. You also take a look at `arsenal` package which provides some facilities for regression output with labels.

Comment: Thanks for everything !

Comment: @GregoryDemin This works so well, thank you. Is there a way to remove the backticks if the output of stargazer we are looking for is directly to html? eg `stargazer(ols, 
          title = "Regression Results",
          label = "tab:test",
          type = "html",
          out = "table1.html") %>% 
  remove_backticks()`

Comment: @JeremyK. `remove_backticks` also works for HTML. You need to save result: `writeLines(res, "test.html")`

Comment: This works well for numerical variables, but how can we make it work for categorical variables?

Comment: @bixiou You need to convert categorical variables to factors with `factor` or `as.factor` before linear regression.